Error Azure Communication Services when sending SMS message through REST API
I wish to send an SMS message to a Dutch mobile phone number from my Logic app (consumption) in Microsoft Azure using (dynamic) Alphanumeric Sender ID.
I have created the required resources in Azure in order to do so.
Next, I followed the Postman tutorial steps closely in order to test the behavior from within Postman. All works fine, from within Postman.
Now, I am trying to configure my Logic app correctly to send the SMS message instead of manually through Postman. Upon sending the SMS message through the REST API I get the following error message:
HTTP 401 - Unauthorized

{   "error": {
"code": "Denied",
"message": "Denied by the resource provider."   } }

I am happy to walk you through the steps I've taken so far:

I created my Azure Logic app (Consumption), it is triggered upon a specific event. This works fine.

I created an Azure Function (OS = Windows, Stack = Node.js, Node.js Version = Node.js 20 LTS) of trigger type HTTP and installed the package 'crypto-js'

I created my Azure Communication Services resource and enabled the (dynamic) Alphanumeric Sender ID and enabled Event Grid

I configured the Azure Logic app to construct the SMS message contents through the 'Compose' action. This way I'm sure it will always be the same when I reuse it in a later step. This is how my JSON object looks like, which will be sent to the ACS REST API through the request body:
{
"from": "Area",
"message": "Hello world!",
"smsRecipients": [
{
"to": "+316xxxxxxxx"
}
],
"smsSendOptions": {
"enableDeliveryReport": true
}
}

Next, I configured my Logic app to send (POST) the outputs of the 'Compose' action (the JSON object) through the Request Body to my Azure Function. The Azure Function is getting triggered just fine.

With a little bit of help from ChatGPT I came up with the following Azure function code, converted/translated from the Postman tutorial:
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js'); // Use crypto-js for hashing and HMAC
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
 // Step 1: Set the Date header to UTC String
 const dateStr = new Date().toUTCString();

 // Step 2: Hash the request body using SHA256 and encode it as Base64
 let requestBody = req.body; // Ensure there's a body
 const hashedBodyStr = CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(requestBody)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

 // Step 3: Get the endpoint and process the Host
 const endpoint = 'https://acs-myendpointname.europe.communication.azure.com'; 
 // Allow passing via query or header
 const hostStr = endpoint.replace('https://', '');   

 // Step 4: Process the URL
 const url = `/sms`

 // Step 5: Construct the string to sign
 const stringToSign = `${req.method}\n${url}\n${dateStr};${hostStr};${hashedBodyStr}`;

 // Step 6: Decode the access key and sign the string using HMAC SHA256
 const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('6LdYArmyververysecretaccesskeyAAAAAZCSUpsh');
 const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

 // Step 7: Add the signature to the Authorization header
 const authorizationHeader = `HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=${signature}`;

 // Respond with headers
 context.res = {
     headers: {
         'Date': dateStr,
         'x-ms-content-sha256': hashedBodyStr,
         'Authorization': authorizationHeader
     },
     body: {
         message: 'Headers set successfully',
         signedString: stringToSign,
         signature: signature
     }
 };

};

My Logic app receives the response perfectly and parses the data. This is how the data looks like from within my Azure Logic app when I look at the outputs of the Azure Function step
{
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
"Date": "Fri, 18 Oct 2024 11:21:43 GMT",
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"x-ms-content-sha256": "FoThiUZWwYdd+Sxxxxxxxxxx99f/AN3DjD20pMCCcms=",
"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length": "695"
},
"body": "{\r\n  "message": "Headers set successfully",\r\n  "varRequestBody": {\r\n    "from": "CompanyName",\r\n    "message": "Hello world!",\r\n    "smsRecipients": [\r\n      {\r\n        "to": "+316xxxxxxxx"\r\n      }\r\n    ],\r\n    "smsSendOptions": {\r\n      "enableDeliveryReport": true\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  "reqOriginalUrl": "https://myAzureFunctionEndpoint.azurewebsites.net/api/generatehmacsignature?code=g17WyRrHtjgE_pOwgaEDtExxxxxxxxxx1CzNeLcRq4pNAzFuFKbRhQ%3d%3d",\r\n  "signedString": "POST\n/sms\nFri, 18 Oct 2024 11:21:43 GMT;acs-myendpointname.europe.communication.azure.com;FoThiUZWwYdd+Sxxxxxxxxxx99f/AN3DjD20pMCCcms=",\r\n  "signature": "RUzjtrWEeTXZvmyverysecretsignature5exChupL0Bc="\r\n}"
}

I added two 'Parse JSON' actions after this to separately parse both the Headers and the Body from the Azure Function outputs. They are referenced in the following step.

As a last step I attempt to send the SMS message through the ACS REST API, and this is where it's going bad:


Method: POST
URI: https://acs-myendpointname.europe.communication.azure.com/sms?api-version=2021-03-07
Headers (Key : Value):

Authorization : HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=@{body('Parse_Azure_Function_Request_Body')?['signature']}

Content-Type : application/json

Date : @body('Parse_Azure_Function_Request_Headers')?['Date']

host : acs-myendpointname.europe.communication.azure.com

x-ms-content-sha256 : @body('Parse_Azure_Function_Request_Headers')?['x-ms-content-sha256']


Body:
I use the exact same JSON object that I had constructed earlier through the 'Compose' action, by referencing the outputs of the 'Compose' action.
I think something went wrong in translating/converting the Postman Pre-request script to my Azure Function code. But I double checked it twice and I can't find the cause of this issue.
I have spoken with a Microsoft ACS Support Engineer (Performance team) and he confirms that the service is working as expected, this is confirmed by the fact that Azure CLI and Postman work.
Now I hope there is someone out the who can help me out identifying what is going wrong, and I hope the information provided helps out.
Many thanks in advance.

refer this  link to Sends a SMS message from a phone number that belongs to the authenticated account.

I tried your code and received the same error: 401 Denied by the resource provider.
You need to change how the string to sign is constructed, compute the HMAC signature, and attach the necessary headers, as shown in the code below.

  const hashedBodyStr = CryptoJS.SHA256(requestBody).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    const hostStr = endpoint.replace('https://', '');

    const urlPath = '/sms?api-version=2021-03-07';

    const stringToSign = `POST\n${urlPath}\n${dateStr};${hostStr};${hashedBodyStr}`;

    const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);

    const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, keyBytes).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    const authorizationHeader = `HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=${signature}`;

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${endpoint}${urlPath}`, requestBody, {
            headers: {
                'Date': dateStr,
                'x-ms-content-sha256': hashedBodyStr,
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
                'Host': hostStr,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        console.log('SMS Sent:', response.status, response.data);


The following Node.js code implements sending SMS messages through Azure Communication Services:

const axios = require('axios');
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

async function sendSms() {
    
    const key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'; 
    const endpoint = 'https://YOUR_ENDPOINT.communication.azure.com'; 


    const fromPhoneNumber = '+12345678901';  
    const toPhoneNumber = '+10987654321';    
    const message = 'Hello from Azure Communication Services!';

    const dateStr = new Date().toUTCString();

    const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
        from: fromPhoneNumber,
        message: message,
        smsRecipients: [{ to: toPhoneNumber }]
    });

  
    const hashedBodyStr = CryptoJS.SHA256(requestBody).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    const hostStr = endpoint.replace('https://', '');

    const urlPath = '/sms?api-version=2021-03-07';

    const stringToSign = `POST\n${urlPath}\n${dateStr};${hostStr};${hashedBodyStr}`;

    const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);

    const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, keyBytes).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    const authorizationHeader = `HMAC-SHA256 SignedHeaders=date;host;x-ms-content-sha256&Signature=${signature}`;

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${endpoint}${urlPath}`, requestBody, {
            headers: {
                'Date': dateStr,
                'x-ms-content-sha256': hashedBodyStr,
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
                'Host': hostStr,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        console.log('SMS Sent:', response.status, response.data);

    } catch (error) {
  
        console.error('Error sending SMS:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}

sendSms();

Output:


Hi Sampath yes I found that article. I am able to make it work from the Azure Function itself now using the axios package, but I want my Logic app to send the HTTP request using the built-in HTTP action. Do you have an example of how I can use my Logic app to send the message (requestBody) and for my Logic app to receive a response from the Azure Function and construct the HTTP call?

glad know it worked . Refer this doc for Logic app to send the HTTP request using the built-in HTTP action
